# How to filter Lucene search with a field by 2 values?

Tags: lucene.net

I have a lucene search where i was trying to filter my search with LanguageIds, but i was unable to do that. I was passing my Languageids like "1,2,3",but its not filtering correctly,its only taking values having languageIds "1,2,3". but i want results having languageIds with "1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,2,3". Can any body tell me how to pass multiple values for a single termQuery in Lucene.net?

Wat i have done so far is

```
          if (languagelds.Contains(","))
            {
                List<String> languageld = languagelds.Trim().Split(',').ToList();
                languageld.ForEach(lid =>
                {
                    TermQuery languageQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("resourceLanguageIds", lid));
                    filterQuery.Add(languageQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                TermQuery languageQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("resourceLanguageIds", languagelds));
                filterQuery.Add(languageQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            }


        filterQuery.Add(productQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        Filter filter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery));
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(100, true);
        Hits hits = null;
        if (sortField != "Rank")
        {
            hits = indexSearch.Search(searchQuery, filter, sort);
            indexSearch.SetDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, true);
        }
        else
        {
            hits = indexSearch.Search(searchQuery, filter);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add the same field multiple times while indexing like

```
doc.Add( new Field(resourceLanguageId,"1"... 

doc.Add( new Field(resourceLanguageId,"2"...

doc.Add( new Field(resourceLanguageId,"3"...
```

Comment: is there any other method to filter from search side without making any changes in indexing?

Comment: try searching for "1" and "1,*" depending in how you stored the field it may work. It's not the best solution, you should follow Anon advice